# nginx wildcard subdomains to different roots

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-status

i want to support all level subdomains to "domain.com" for my configuration. That's possible with:

```
server_name "~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.com$";
```

My root looks like this:

```
set $subDirectory subdomains/$sub/;
set $root /var/www/domain.com/$subDirectory/www/;
root $root;
```

Example:

"abc.domain.com" will be /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/abc/www/

Now i want to support all level subdomains. For every sub i want to set in root between domain.com/**HERE**/www/ subdomains/$sub/. How can i do it?

"abc.domain.com" will be /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/abc/www/

"test.abc.domain.com" should be /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/abc/subdomains/test/www/

"hello.test.abc.domain.com" should be /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/abc/subdomains/test/subdomains/hello/www/

Currently "$sub" is for the last example hello.test.abc;.

Could i copy "$sub" to "$subRoot" and can replace all the points (.) on $subRoot with "/subdomains/"?
$subRoot looks then like "hello/subdomains/test/subdomains/abc"